# ios IAP app submition

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I will soon submit my app which has auto-renewal subscription. The *[preparing for app review](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/AppReview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH10-SW1)* documentation says "Provide UI to begin the restoration process." My app does not need this, do I have to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will have to implement that or else your In-App Purchase will be rejected. If app gets uninstalled by mistake, user has to be provided with a functionality of restoring his purchase.

Comment: The user also needs the ability to restore a subscription on a new or additional device

Comment: @Paulw11 user's data stores in my server ,even though user uninstalls app,whose data will not be lost.do i need to provide UI to begin the storation process?

Comment: You must implement the restore purchase function.  It is a requirement as per the document you linked to.

Comment: If you are gonna do it automatically, then Restore will not be required. Even me has done the same thing.